# DataGrid not shirking to fit into the containing grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grid

I have the following structure in my WPF application. (Using Prism and Regions)

Window---->
    UserControl---->
    DockPanel------>
        Grid(2X2)------>Row0Col0--
                  Grid (2X1)------>
            ItemsControl------>
                UserControl(injected into ItemsControl with Prism)----->
                    DockPanel----->
                        DataGrid.(60 rows, 10 columns)

The behavior that I expect is that the DataGrid will size itself to fit the size of the grid cell and display both scrollbars because it is too big to fit. But it doesnt. It remains its maximum size and cuts out of the edges of the grid cell. All cells of both grids have no size specifications (Auto Sized). When I explicitly specify datagrid's height and width, I see the scrollbars, but of course I don't want to do that.

Please help!.
Thanks

I have saved the screenshots at the following link.
http://s1199.photobucket.com/albums/aa467/vikasgoyalgzs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say: "All cells of both grids have no size specifications (Auto Sized)" - this is where the problem is. When the `grid` cell is `auto` sized the `grid` gives the content in that cell as much space as it wants (doesn't matter if it fits in the window or not). To fix it you have to put your `DataGrid` into a star-sized cell.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>      
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Border Grid.Row="0">
     <!-- Content that will take as much space as it wants -->
   </Border>

   <Border Grid.Row="1">
     <!-- Content that will take all the remaining space -->
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the screenshots you provided...

First, get rid of the `DockPanel` in the top level control. `DockPanel` gives its child all the space it asks for.  If it is not a "fill" child (`LastChildFill="True"`). Use `grid` instead of `DockPanel` (i.e. at the top level a `grid` with two rows - one auto-sized for the menu and the second star-size for the rest of the stuff, the in that star-size row put another `grid` for you items controls, etc.).

Remember, whenever you put the content either in an auto-size cell in a grid or in a `DockPanel` with dock type different than `Fill`, the content will take as much space as it required without showing a scroll bar (it will go beyond the window).

**UPDATE 2:** Looking at the new screenshots (see comments to this post)...

OK, I think I see the problem. The thing is that `ItemsControl` uses `StackPanel` to display its children, but `StackPanel` also gives its children all the space they want (your `DataGrid` thinks that it has enough space to render itself without scroll bars).

To fix that you need to put your items controls inside an `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respons Pavlo...But unfortunately, this didnt help much. Let me give a little bit more details...My grid has a UserControl in each row. The first row UserControl has the datagrid and the second row Usercontrol has a TabControl. By doing what you mentioned, my tabControl takes almost 25% of the space because it has that much content. And datagrid takes the rest of the space. But it still doesnt resize itself, it shows a little more data than it was showing before. Still cutting on the side...:(

Comment: Well, it is very hard to tell what is wrong without seeing the actual markup... Maybe you could post a simplified XAML of the entire UI structure? Or some screenshots?

Comment: I have saved the screenshots on the following link.   http://s1199.photobucket.com/albums/aa467/vikasgoyalgzs/

Comment: Pavlo...I really appericiate you helping me with this..I did as you said, but results has changed a bit. I have uploaded updated xaml here...  http://s1199.photobucket.com/albums/aa467/vikasgoyalgzs/Updated%20Screenshots/

Comment: Sorry, I meant results have not changed a bit.

Comment: Pavlo, You are a genius! I cant thank you enough...I think that problem really needed an expert..I did not do exactly as you said, but i changed ItemsPanelTemplate of ItemsControl to a Grid (again following your directions from the previous post) and it works like a charm! Thanks a million Pavlo!!

Comment: Yep, you are welcome :) I didn't suggest to change ItemsPanel because I thought you needed the stack panel functionality. And if you change the ItemsPanel to Grid probably you don't need the ItemsControl for your region (if there is more then one control in that region, they will be displayed on on top of another). Anyway, if you find my answer useful please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.